3D Print showing strings
I have had no issues printing until now. I tried to print the curved object shown in the picture below.
The strings you see are to tight, it seems to make the arc. It's like the print would not do the arc because it was not long enough.
Thoughts?


You have two issues going on,

Oozing
The nozzle appears to leak filament on moving the nozzle, this can be fixed by tuning the retraction settings for length and speed, filament print temperature, travel speed and some slicer settings as combing on the first layer.
Adhesion
The primary problem with the outer perimeter of the inner side of the curved print object is adhesion. The perimeter does not stick to the plate and as a result moves away from the intended print position to follow the movement of the nozzle; i.e. the nozzle drags the just deposited, not adhering filament so that a smaller radius deposition is observed. To have the filament stick better you need to have a proper heated bed temperature, a proper initial Z-offset (usually paper thickness distance) and a proper trammed build surface.

